# Is it possible to connect an Android device to a WCF or any other .NET web service?

Tags: android, .net, wcf, web-services

I want to create an Android app to connect with a server and it's DB. In order to communicate with the server can I use a .NET web service? and what sort of a service should I use?

Comment: yes you can connect via webservice for that you have to call soap webservice. for soap webservice you can find my below anwser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757728/org-ksoap2-serialization-soapserializationenvelope/20760839#20760839

Answer (score 1):

Webservices is the bridge between the server and your android app.For accessing the DB from the server you have to write the webservices that returns the data in json format or other.

For JSON you have to use JSON Parsing that will parse the data coming from the server and get it on to your app. And for sopa webservices you have to use KSOAP library and parse the data.

FOr **JSON** Parsing refer this:-http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

For **soap** webservices:-http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html

Hope it helps you a lot.