# Web Service Connection in Android

Tags: java, android, web-services

I'm trying to understand webservice in android so I wanna connect webservice in order to display data from it.

I have a big project and it has a webservice How can I connect it and get data from it?

There are lots of class that extends from `SoapObject`,`KvmSerializable` and import like these:

```
import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
```

How can I get data from webservice?

Comment: Uhhh https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/

Comment: you can check my answer for soap web service http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757728/org-ksoap2-serialization-soapserializationenvelope/20760839#20760839

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommand you the Android training for Network operations, which is a great start to learn how to consume web services.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html

And especially the one about XML (since it sounds like you want to work with SOAP)

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html